# Android - как узнать размер физической памяти на устройстве?

Tags: java, android, мобильная-разработка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно определить, сколько постоянной памяти  в устройстве и сколько этой памяти  используется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться классом [`StatFs`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html). Доступное место можно получить чем-то вроде такого:

```
StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
long availableSpace =
    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2 ?
        (long)statFs.getAvailableBlocks() * (long)statFs.getBlockSize():
        statFs.getAvailableBlocksLong() * statFs.getBlockSizeLong();
```

Если не требуется поддержка более старых версий, чем Android 4.3, то можно оставить только нижнюю строку: `long availableSpace = statFs.getAvailableBlocksLong() * statFs.getBlockSizeLong()`

Для получения общего объёма воспользуйтесь методами `getBlockCount` или `getBlockCountLong` вместо `getAvailableBlocks`/`getAvailableBlocksLong`.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое а то я весь интернет уже перерил

Comment: @Vlad Если ответ Вам помог, отметьте его как правильный